# passing and read javascript variable to smarty

Tags: javascript, smarty, var

How can i read a javascript var from smarty?? like this

```
<script>
  var number =10;
</script>
{if 'javascript variable (number)' == 10}
    do something....
{/if}
```

THanks!!

Comment: You can't. Smarty is executed on the server while javascript is executed in the client.  At the point of generateing the content, the javascript is nothing but a collection of text with no inherent meaning.  Of course if you have `number=10` hardcoded, there is no reason that this should not be able to reside in a PHP variable, and be injected into the javascript dynamically.

Comment: oh too bad, is not harcoded its an example, ok looking for another solution. THanks!!

Comment: If the value is really determined in javascript, you will need to pass it to the backend in one of a number of ways - via GET/POST, via cookie setting, or via an AJAX call. The bottom line is that your server script must be passed this value so it can use it for conditional logic.  On the other hand, you could just output the conditional content to HTML and have it hidden and then control display via javascript.